# Do Not Escape setAttrib() Method (Zend_Form)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I would like to add an attribute to some form elements in the action controller, I can do it like this:

```
$form->element_name->setAttrib('description', '<a href="/controller/action">Anchor</a>');
```

However in the above example the second argument gets escaped. I would like to have it unescaped. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$decorator->setEscape(false);` on Description decorator. Retieve it like `$descriptionDEcorator = $element->getDecorator('Description');`

Comment: I set that on the decorator, the problem is that it still gets escaped if I set the description in the controller. In the form file it works but the description changes depending on request parameters so I have to set it in the controller.

Comment: I'd suggest checking if you're not altering decorators anywhere else then form's init() method. This looks like you set escaping and then somewhere set different set of decorators.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to [experiment](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-4299) a bit but typically

```
$element->setAttrib("escape", false);
```

should work. I'm using it to not escape the content in a `Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox` subclass right now. There's a `setEscape` method in the Decorator abstract that I believe this flags but the documentation isn't clear (as made obvious by the "enhancement" request).